# How can i get all of the 2nd line only of my stats.txt file?

Tags: batch-file

i currently have this command for a batch file

```
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=\n" %i in (stats.txt) do echo %i
```

with the contents of stats.txt being

```
Title = Subaru's Great Rehab Strategy
URL = http://dynasty-scans.com/chapters/subarus_great_rehab_strategy
Tags = Subaru x Tsukasa[|]Yuri[|]
No. of Pages = 3
```

^ NOTE: the final line is actually blank

[image: notepad++]

the idea of the line of code is to return the 2nd line with `URL`. the end goal would be that i would run this line in some sort of loop going though a series of ~12000+ stats.txt files and collecting all the `URL` lines into a single file

but when i run the command i get this

[image: cmd]

as you can see it has skipped the first line but it's cutting off where the `n` in `dynasty` and outputting the last 3 lines.

now if i remove `delims=\n` i get the same 3 lines but i don't get the first word before the space which seems to indicate that the value of `delims` is what splits a line into *"tokens"* which then i just grab the first one (and space must be the default)

when i go into notepad++, open the Find and Replace Dialog, turn Search Mode to extended and look for "\r\n" i get taken to the end of each line which is why i chose `delims` to be \n assuming this would then make the entire line one token

So my question is **How can i get all of the 2nd line only of my stats.txt file?**

Answer (score 5):

The `for /f` loop already treats the carriage return and / or line feed as an end-of-line.  No need to specify it as a delimiter.  With `delims=\n` you're actually saying that all literal backslashes *and* letter n's should be treated as token delimiters.  If you want the whole line, what you want is `"skip=1 delims="`.

Just out of habit, when reading the contents of a file with a `for /f` loop, I find it useful to enable `usebackq` just in case the filename / path contains a space or ampersand.  That allows you to quote the filename to protect against such potential treachery.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

for /F "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%I in ("stats.txt") do if not defined URL set "URL=%%~I"
echo %URL%
```

---

Put into context, to use this to read many files named stats.txt and output the URLs into a single collection, enclose the whole thing in another `for` loop and enable delayed expansion.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

>URLs.txt (
    for /R %%N in ("*stats.txt") do (
        for /F "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%I in ("%%~fN") do (
            if not defined URL set "URL=%%~I"
        )
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo(!URL!
        endlocal
        set "URL="
    )
)

echo Done.  The results are in URLs.txt.
```

If you want to strip the "URL = " from the beginning of each line and keep only the address, you could try changing your `for /F` parameters to `"usebackq skip=1 tokens=3"` if all the files follow the same format of `URL`<kbd>Space</kbd>`=`<kbd>Space</kbd>`http://etc.`.  If you can't depend on that, or if any of the URLs might contain unencoded spaces, you could also change `echo(!URL!` to `echo(!URL:*http=http!`

Comment: This runs fine but when i go to run it for a different stats.txt (remember i'm just doing 1 with the first test, end goal is to do it for over 12000 files) it just outputs the same line as the first time. it wont chnage until i close off Command Prompt and reopen it and rerun it for the new file

Comment: @Memor-X That’s the correct behavior for rojo’s code. Note the part `if not defined URL set "URL=%%~I"`.

Comment: Or in other words, you have to `set "URL="` before you read the next file

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a `FOR /F` loop, you can also read it with a `SET /P`

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
< stats.txt (
  set /p line1=
  set /p URL_Line=
)
echo(!URL_Line!
```

Comment: Elegant solution.  I like this better than mine, to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

Try this from the command line:

```
(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %i in ('findstr "URL" stats*.txt') do echo %j) > output.txt
```

> the idea ... is to return the 2nd line with `URL`

If you want to insert this line in a Batch file, just double the percent signs.

Comment: I would spend a `/b` to `findstr` ("line starts with...")

Answer (score 1):

Try this from the prompt:

```
(for /f "tokens=1*delims=]" %a in ('find /v /n "" *.csv^|findstr /l /b "[2]"') do @echo %b)>u:\r1.txt
```

Where - I used `*.csv` for testing (substitute your own filemask) and I used `u:\r1.txt` for the result - substitute as seems fit (but don't output to a file tat fits your selected filemask !)

It works by prefixing each line in each file with a bracketed number `[n]` (`find` - `/n`=and number `/v` lines that do **not** match `""` - an empty string); then selecting those lines that `/l` - literally `/b` at the beginning of the line match `"[2]"`.

The result is all of the second-lines of the files, preceded by the literal "[2]". All we need to do then is tokenise the result, first token up to delimiter "]" will be "[2" assgned to `%%a` and remainder-of line (token `*`) will be assigned to `%%b`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=\n" %i in (stats.txt) do echo %i && goto :eof
```

I haven't tested it as I don't have access to a Windows machine at the moment, but that should exit the `for`-loop after the first iteration, which is what you want.

Comment: when i run this it doesnt output anything. even after i alter the `%i` to be `%1` (as i am quite sure they had to match)

Comment: @Memor-X I didn't even notice that. I think number variables (`%0`-`%9`) are reserved although I could be wrong. Please try it with both being `%i`.

Comment: it's outputting now however it is still doing the same as it does in my question just with now the `echo ` part has `&& goto :eof` at the end (but i have fixed it cutting things off at the n). [here's a screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqxme.png)